# Is there an easy way (hopefully with ES6+) to apply mutations to array values base on config objects?

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to write a function that allows me to configure array values. I would like to create config objects, like so:

```
var words = [
    'spacejump',
    'apples',
    'graphics',
    'javascript',
    'peaches'
];

var configs = [{
    upper_case:'first',
    length:[6,8]
},{
    upper_case:'last',
    length:[7,9],
    strip:'vowels'
},{
    length:10,
    strip:'consonants'
}]
```

and then apply those configurations to another array of strings (words in this case) and output the results, like so:

```
[
    [
        "Apples",
        "Graphics",
        "Peaches"
    ],
    [
        "spcjmP",
        "grphcS",
        "pchS"
    ],
    [
        "aai"
    ]
]
```

I am struggling to get started as I am trying to filter the results but into new individual arrays.

```
function configurate(config) {
    for (var filter in config) {
        switch (filter) {
            case upper_case:
            //capitalize either first or last letter
            case length:
            //include words with said length
            case strip:
            //strip vowels or consonants
        }
    }
}

function applyConfig(array, configs) {
    //forEach() word in array apply config
    //this is where I am confused a bit,
    //
    //
}
```

This is what I have so far, I left out too much implementation because I am worried that I am not doing this efficiently.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on that example array you provided? What does each sub-array mean? How did `Apples` become `spcjmP`? And why does the last array contain only one item?

Comment: My apologies! I shall edit! To clarify, the array could be any list of words. The only configurations at this point are to choose length, first/last letter capitalized and striping vowels or consonants.

Comment: Use `map`, not `forEach`. Your `configurate` function seems fine given your custom configuration format

Comment: I would say get it working first, then worry about efficiency.

Comment: True, I will begin to implement it with map now and see how that goes. Much appreciated everyone.

Comment: @Bergi could you possibly elaborate. I am curious as this aspect was scrutinized when I showed someone who does hiring at a successful startup (I was curious). I figured forEach was good for just manipulating the data. Thanks!

Comment: @penntreetz, map is faster and guarantees immutability. Also lets you do method chaining which looks a lot cleaner imo. With forEach you have to handle this yourself if it is the wanted behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lambda functions to create the config operations and include these in your config objects.

Now you can loop over the configs array and for each word that matches the length requirement of the config, apply all functions to it.

Here is an example implementation. Could probably be done better in many ways, but I think it does what you want.

```js
var words = [
    'spacejump',
    'apples',
    'graphics',
    'javascript',
    'peaches'
];

const config_functions = {
  upper_case: {
    first: s => s[0].toUpperCase() + s.slice(1),
    last: s => s.slice(0, s.length - 1) + s[s.length - 1].toUpperCase()
  },
  strip: {
    vowels: s => s.replace(/[aeiou]/ig,''),
    consonants: s => s.replace(/[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvxz]/ig,'')
  },
  range: (s, ...range) => range[1] ? (s.length >= range[0] && s.length <= range[1]) : s.length >= range[0]
};


var configs = [{
    modifiers: [
      config_functions.upper_case.first
    ],
    length: s => config_functions.range(s,6,8)
},{
    modifiers: [
      config_functions.upper_case.last,
      config_functions.strip.vowels
    ],
    length: s => config_functions.range(s,7,9)
},{
    modifiers: [
      config_functions.strip.consonants
    ],
    length: s => config_functions.range(s,10)
}];

let res = configs.map(config => words
                      .filter(word => config.length(word))
                      .map(word => config.modifiers.reduce((acc, func) => acc = func(acc), word)));

console.log(res);
```